# iMacros how to add custom text to extracted TXT

Tags: csv, extract, imacros

I have this code that checks for text on a page and then saves the text to a csv:

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=TXT:* EXTRACT=TXT
SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=C:\test FILE=test.csv
```

Is it possible to add my own text to the extracted TXT, I tried this:

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=TXT:*+{{!CLIPBOARD}} EXTRACT=TXT
SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=C:\test FILE=test.csv
```

So, this time I want it to save to the CSV as "textInDiv","clipboardValue"

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=TXT:* EXTRACT=TXT
ADD !EXTRACT {{!CLIPBOARD}}
SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=C:\test FILE=test.csv
```

http://wiki.imacros.net/ADD

Answer (score 1):

to save to the CSV as "textInDiv","clipboardValue", try this:

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=TXT:* EXTRACT=TXT
SET !EXTRACT {{!EXTRACT}}[EXTRACT]{{!CLIPBOARD}}
SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=C:\test FILE=test.csv
```